# How to drag and drop drawn polygon on image

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas, coordinates, polygon

How to drag and drop drawn polygon on image

1. Currently drawing a polygon on image with mouse clicks , i can do undo operation for the latest drawn polygon but how to do drag and drop operation for selected polygon

   2. And update the coordinates when position got changed
   3. save the coordinates in a array (Currently i am doing it)

```js
//radius of click around the first point to close the draw
var END_CLICK_RADIUS = 15;
//the max number of points of your polygon
var MAX_POINTS = 4;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var isStarted = false;
var polygons = [];

var canvas = null;
var ctx;
var image;

window.onload = function() {
  var background = document.getElementById('justanimage');
  //initializing canvas and draw color
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  };
  image.src = 'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/2fe/butterfly-1390152.jpg';
  canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    if (isStarted) {
      //drawing the next line, and closing the polygon if needed
      if (Math.abs(x - polygons[polygons.length - 1][0].x) < END_CLICK_RADIUS && Math.abs(y - polygons[polygons.length - 1][0].y) < END_CLICK_RADIUS) {
        isStarted = false;
      } else {
        polygons[polygons.length - 1].push(new Point(x, y));
        if (polygons[polygons.length - 1].length >= MAX_POINTS) {
          isStarted = false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      //opening the polygon
      polygons.push([new Point(x, y)]);
      isStarted = true;
    }
  }, false);

  //we just save the location of the mouse
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
  }, false);

  //refresh time
  setInterval("draw();", 5);
}

//object representing a point
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

//resets the application
function reset() {
  isStarted = false;
  points = null;
  document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = " ";
}

//draws the current shape
function draw() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
  polygons.forEach(function(points, i) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    points.forEach(function(p, j) {
      if (j) {
        ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
      } else {
        ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
      }
    });
    if (i + 1 === polygons.length && isStarted) { // just the last one
      ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    } else {
      ctx.lineTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  });

}

function undoLastPoint() {
  // remove the last drawn point from the drawing array
  polygons.pop();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<button type="button" onclick="undoLastPoint()">Undo</button>
<img id="justanimage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The canvas-element renderes in "immediate mode" which means that the canvas doesn't keep track of shapes that have been drawn. It "forgetts" everything that has been drawn right after it has been drawn. So there is no built-in way to select a shape or a path and drag it, since the canvas doesn't know about the shape anymore. You have to build this on your own.

1. Select a path:
   While drawing you can use `CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInPath()`  which returns `true` if a coordinate like the coordinates of a mouse-click is within the current path. "Current" means this function needs to be called right after the path has been drawn and before the path is removed from the context-stack.
   (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath)
2. Dragging:
   To be able to drag the path after the one that has been clicked has been detected using `isPointInPath()`, you need to store the coordinates (and maybe the color) and translate the old coordinates to the new position of the mouse and redraw the path.
   In order to do this animated, so that a user can see how the path is moving with the mouse you need to redraw the whole image, as often as you can. This can be done using `window.requestAnimationFrame()` 
   (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations)